# Cannot import name ProtocolError [RaspberryPi, Jasper]

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I had installed sphinx and Jasper on my RPI. When I'm trying to start Jasper - i got this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/jasper/jasper.py", line 14, in <module>
    from client import vocabcompiler, stt, jasperpath
    File "/home/pi/jasper/client/stt.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import charade as chardet
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in                           <module>
    from . import urllib3
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16,         in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .connection import (
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .util import (
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .retry import Retry
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import (
    ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolError
```

Who can help me with this error? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

you should

```html
pip install urllib3
```